# hg qnew: abort: working directory revision is not qtip

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I am trying to create a new patch. So I wrote:

```
hg qnew -e -f mypatch.patch
```

But I get a message:

```
abort: working directory revision is not qtip
```

What exactly is the error here and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

`qtip` is the tag that represents the tip of the currently applied patches and must be the parent of the working directory to create patches when one is already applied.  You can't have more than one patch series applied at a time, so you have to update to the current tip of the applied patches to create another patch in the currently applied series.